# Mutli Replace in Multiple Files

Tags: python, shell, replace, command-prompt

Whats the quickest and smartest way to use Find and Replace dynamically in SQL Management Studio?

I have 100 files where I need to perform the below replaces

Replace test with ActualTest
Replace this with ThisNow
Replace ABC with QPR etc....

I currently find and replace in all documents together but there are over 25 replaces/variables to be done was just wondering if I can do a mass replace all at once.

Perl, Shell, anything works?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Awk would work:

```
awk '
/test/ { gsub("test","ActualTest") }
/this/ { gsub("this","ThisNow") }
/ABC/  { gsub("ABC","QPR") }
{ print }' test.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use awk but is there anything that i can run on command prompt and do *.sql?

Comment: the files are located on windows server and they are .sql files